# how to load multiple uiimage in uiscrollview horizontally?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I made a UIScrollView and Showing images from Array but images are not showing

here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

imageScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13.0, 50.0, 292.0, 69.0)];

    [self makeScroll];

}

-(void)makeScroll
{
    imageScroll.delegate = self;

    imageScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    int arrayCount = [myArray count];

    imageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(arrayCount * 101.0, 69.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)

    {

        participantView = [[UIView alloc]init];

        if (i == 0) {

            participantView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 2.0, 91.0, 67.0);

        }

        else {

            participantView.frame = CGRectMake(101.0*i, 2.0, 91.0, 67.0);

        }

        participantView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        //declaring the view in which image object will be added
        UIImageView *bannerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] 

initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,91.0,67.0)];

        //taking out the image object
        UIImage *imageNamed = [UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];

        //resizing the image

   // UIImage *imageNamed2 = [imageNamed 

imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(91.0,67.0)];

        //setting the resized image in UIImageView

        [bannerImage setImage:imageNamed];

        //clear the bg
        bannerImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        bannerImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        bannerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [bannerImage setNeedsLayout];

        bannerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,91.0,67.0);

    [participantView addSubview:bannerImage];



            [imageScroll addSubview:participantView];

    }

    [self.view addSubview:imageScroll];


}
```

Can anyone please tell me where i'm doing mistake

Problem is: the image is not showing in scrollview

Comment: Format your code. Also, this is not related to Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 format code ? i just paste it from my file, can you please please tell me the soloution from where i'm doing mistake why images are not showing in my uiscrollview ?

Comment: this seems like a classic use for a TableView

Comment: what's the content in your myArray?  make sure you can load image correctly    & ***[UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];***  seems you loaded the same image everytime

Answer (score 2):

Images are not showing because you added images as subview of UIView.

Keep Hierarchy in mind.

First add images as a subview of scrollview then add scrollview as a subview of UIView.

Or if you are using storyboard then you can set hierarchy directly from there.

Comment: it's fine if the imageview is not directly add to the controler.view

Answer (score 0):

```
   scrl_venuelist.delegate=self;
    scrl_venuelist.contentSize =CGSizeMake(273 * [imageArr count], 137);

    int scroll_x=0;
    for (int i=0; i < [imageArr count]; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scroll_x, 0, 100, 100)] autorelease];
        img.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[[imageArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ImgName"]];
        [scrl_venuelist addSubview:img];
        scroll_x = scroll_x + 273;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer following code . This is working for me :

```
            scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50, 768, 40)];
            int scrollWidth=60;
            for (int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
            {
                UIImageView *imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth,8,50,40)];
                imageView1.image=[array objectAtIndex:i];
                [scrollView addSubview:imageView1];
                scrollWidth=scrollWidth+80;
            }
            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 30)];
            [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

set no of pages

```
    static NSUInteger numberOfPages = [imageArr count];
```

in ViewDidLoad

```
    howItWorksScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 640)];
    howItWorksScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    howItWorksScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(howItWorksScrollView.frame.size.width * numberOfPages, howItWorksScrollView.frame.size.height);
    howItWorksScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    howItWorksScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    howItWorksScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    howItWorksScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:howItWorksScrollView];

    int k,i;
    int btnX = 70, btnY = 25;

    int count =0;


    for (k = 0; k < numberOfPages; k++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            if (count < [imageArray count])
            {
                UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btnX, btnY, 180, 180)];
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[imageArray objectAtIndex:k]]];
                imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                [howItWorksScrollView addSubview:imageView];
                [imageView release];

                count++;

                btnX = btnX + 180 + 70 + 70;

            }

            btnX = btnX - 320;

        }
        btnX = btnX + 320;
        btnY = 25;

    }
```

Comment: where are you setting the most important content view for the scroll view in your code ?

Comment: pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
        pageControl.currentPage = 0;

Comment: Dont know ,I think you should give your answer in standard format .

Comment: did you add this code inside your code?now tell me exactly what is a problem? Try this properly it works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at VSScrollview. Its a very simple to use class. It is used the same way as UITableview is used and like UITableview reuses its cell, VSScrollView reuses its view so you do not have to worry about handling memory when you have large number of subviews over your Scrollview. [VSScrollview link](https://github.com/iVishal/VSScroller.git)

Answer (score 0):

[SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) by Nicklockwood is a good library for handling views in horizontal scrollview.

**From Documentation:**

> SwipeView is a class designed to simplify the implementation of
>   horizontal, paged scrolling views on iOS. It is based on a
>   UIScrollView, but adds convenient functionality such as a
>   UITableView-style dataSource/delegate interface for loading views
>   dynamically, and efficient view loading, unloading and recycling.
>
> SwipeView's interface and implementation is based on the iCarousel
>   library, and should be familiar to anyone who has used iCarousel.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Friends For Helping Me

i got the problem from where i was mistaking,

In My Array the images are in URL , so i did this and its working

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0f, 91.0f, 67.0f)];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [myArray objectAtIndex:i]]];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

[imageView setImage:img];
```

problem solved :-)